# find which web server rails app using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver

I am new to rails.
How do I find which web server rails app using?
Command to start app is

```
rails s puma -dp 80 -e production
```

Also I see apache2 is not running on server. So I guess Puma is being used. But I am not sure Puma is webserver, I found [link](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/) which describes setting up Puma with nginx. So Am I using nginx? Also where do I find log of this web server?

Comment: log of your application you can see in the log folder there is production.log,development.log...

Answer (score 0):

Puma can be used as a webserver, since the command line appears to be setting the port to 80, this is probably how it is configured in your case. This works fine for the most part, but a more common configuration is to use apache or nginx as a reverse proxy and to serve static assets. (the stuff in public/assets). Requests for non-static content are then forwarded to puma.